# Spell checker for word 2007 is not working

Tags: microsoft-word, language, spell-check

From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1279961/spell-checker-in-ms-word-2007-works-for-some-languages-but-not-for-others?newreg=f6a6be22a47e41b7a2a7514e42100595) it is clear that a language without the ABC checkers will not work for spell checking. I’m aware of this. What is not answered there is what to do when one wants to use a certain language that doesn’t have the ABC checkers. How one activates (install) this particular language into word.

EDIT: Tried to install all three language service packs from Microsoft but the following error message appear.

[image]

Setup: Windows 10 64 bit, Office 2007

Comment: One install the dictionary / language pack?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia. Made an edit. Could you check please.

Comment: I suggest you google the language + word dic...